# Better way to extract coordinates from a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract coordinates from a string.

The string I have has this form:

```
string Coord = @"
      at point  X=-277923.7300  Y=16462.7700  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277816.6200  Y=16311.1500  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277629.1900  Y=16109.7100  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277573.4000  Y=16055.5600  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277524.3100  Y=16023.0700  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277508.6900  Y=15986.2400  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277488.6100  Y=15866.0200  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277466.3000  Y=15766.3800  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277421.6700  Y=15710.0700  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277281.0900  Y=15595.2700  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277234.2300  Y=15547.6100  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277185.1400  Y=15469.6400  Z=   0.0000
      at point  X=-277091.4900  Y=15354.1300  Z=   0.0000:;
```

I want to extract all the X and Y (dont care about the Z) into a List of coordinates.

This is the Coordinates class:

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public Coordinates(double Long, double Lat)
    {
        this.Longitude = Long;
        this.Latitude = Lat;
    }
}
```

I was recommended to use `Regex` And since I was completly new to it, I struggled a little but managed to have something ready.

**This is what I have done so far:**

```
private List<Coordinates> ExtractCoordinates(string Coordinates)
    {

        List<Coordinates> lstOfCoordinates = new List<Coordinates>();

        //I managed to put this regex together after some trial and error
        //This regex will extract this pattern : " X=(any decimal) Y=(any decimal)"

        Regex reg = new Regex("(X=)-?\\d+\\.?\\d+\\s+(Y=)-?\\d+\\.?\\d+");

        //I get the matches and save them in a list
        MatchCollection collection = reg.Matches(Coord);
        List<string> lstOfMatches = (from Match match in collection
                                     select match.Value).ToList();

        //At this point I have alist of string having this form: "X=-277923.7300  Y=16462.7700" 

        //I had no idea how to proceed from here so I did it in a bad way
        //Basically I just Cut the string when I detect the first '=' 
        //and then take the rest until the Y. I remove the = and trim it 
        //and then parse it to double this is the X
        //Same logic for the Y coordinates
        foreach (string match in lstOfMatches)
        {
            double X = double.Parse(match.Substring(match.IndexOf('='), match.IndexOf('Y') - match.IndexOf('=')).Replace("=","").Trim());
            double Y = double.Parse(match.Substring(match.IndexOf("Y=")).Replace("Y=", "").Trim());
            lstOfCoordinates.Add(new Coordinates(X, Y));
        }
        return lstOfCoordinates;
    }
```

Well basically it works but I feel it is not a good way to do it.

So I am looking for a better way to do it. Maybe do the whole logic using only Regex or any suggestions on a cleaner way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = Regex.Matches(Coord, @"X=(?<X>-?\d+.?\d+)\s+Y=(?<Y>\d+.?\d+)");

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X={0} Y={1}", results[i].Groups["X"], results[i].Groups["Y"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groups to capture the actual numbers. Also, use the @"" notation to reduce backslashes.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(X=)-?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+(Y=)-?(\d+(\.\d+)?)");
```

Look at Match.Groups